# How to disable AdMob logs?

Tags: android, admob, logcat

I understood that it's not good practice to publish an app with logs, so i disabled all my log calls.

Now AdMob logs every time an ad is displayed, How can i cancel that? i don't seem to find any information about this topic in the documentation, and i've read that you can use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) but that seems like a bad solution.

Isn't there someway to disable 3rd party logs?

Comment: Well, if admob sdk doesn't have a method/API to disable loggings, then you can't disable it. It all depends on how Google build the library, they could have left the logging enabled without a way to disable it.

Comment: The Admob SDK does not come with a way to disable it; however, there are other ways in order to disable the output of these logs because theses logs are special for developers.

Comment: Havn't tried it yet but as it's not the first answer that says to use proguard, i assumed it's the only way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily this has already been answered. The best thing to do is simply turn on proguard in your application.

Turn on Proguard: [Turning Proguard On/Off Using Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642030/turning-proguard-on-off-using-properties)

Then simply add this to the proguard.cfg here:

Add to proguard.cfg: [Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/deactivate-any-calls-to-log-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this)

One Proguard is on and you add that to the proguard.cfg, you can simply export the signed application and it will be gone. I just tested this yesterday.

Regards,