# Admob sends messages in "Ads" tag

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, logcat

There is an AdMob banner in my game. I can see the messages in "Ads" tags on LogCat of Eclipse. These messages are very useful during the development. Now my game is completed. Should I try to find a way to remove the source of these AdMob library messages? Are these messages problem with my game performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably should get rid of the log entries for two reasons.

First,  they do have a performance impact, mainly because it usually includes performance-heavy String operations and additional I/O load.

Second, Google asks you to remove logging in production applications according to their [Configure Applications for Release](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-configure) document.

You should be able to disable the log entries by adding an explicit ProGuard config, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108078/how-to-disable-admob-logs).